# n-pipeline producing EOF on end

Tags: c, shell, operating-system

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#include <string.h>

void tokenizer(char* input, char** output) { //My tokenizer
  char* input_dup = strdup(input);
  output[0] = strtok(input_dup, " ");
  int i = 1;
  while ((output[i] = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL) {
   i++; 
  }
}

void run_command(char** args, int* fd) { //no pipe
  pid_t pid = fork();

  if (pid < 0) {
   printf("Forking failed...\n"); 
  }
  else if (pid == 0) {
    close(fd[0]);
    if (fd[1] != 1)
      dup2(fd[1], 1);
    execvp(args[0], args);
    printf("Command failed...\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  else {
    close(fd[1]);
    wait(pid);
    char buff[1];

    while (read(fd[0], buff, 1) > 0) {
      if (buff[0] == EOF || buff[0] == '\0') {
    printf("Caught something, returning out...");
    return;
      }
      else {
    printf("%c", buff[0]);
      }      
    }
  }
}

//pipeline function
void run_pipe(char** args, int* fd) {
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0) {
   printf("Forking failed...\n"); 
  }
  else if (pid == 0) {
    if (fd[1] != 1) {
      dup2(fd[1], 1);
    }
    execvp(args[0], args);
    printf("Command failed...\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  else {
    close(fd[1]);
    if (fd[0] != 0) {
     dup2(fd[0], 0);
    }
    wait(pid);
  }         
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  printf ("Starting myshell (mysh) \n..\n..\n");

  while (1) {
    char cwd[1024];

    printf ("mysh :: %s -> ", getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)));

    char ch[1024];
    memset(ch, 0, 1023); //for cleanup
    char c = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while (c != '\n') {
      c = getchar();
      if (c == EOF) {
    printf ("EOF Received, exiting...\n");
    return 0;
     }
      if (c != '\n')
     ch[i] = c;
      i++;
    }

    if (ch[0] != '\0') {

      char* tokens[128];
      tokenizer(ch, tokens);

      //first check for keywords
      if (strcmp(tokens[0], "cd") == 0) {
    if (chdir(tokens[1]) < 0) {
      printf("ERROR: Directory %s does not exist\n", tokens[1]);
    }
      }
      else if (strcmp(tokens[0], "exit") == 0) {
      printf("Leaving shell...\n");
      return 0;
      }
      else {
    char* commands[50];
    memset(commands, 0, sizeof(commands));
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    int fd[2];

    //try something different...

    while (tokens[j] != NULL) {
     if (strcmp(tokens[j], "|") == 0) {
       commands[k] = NULL;
       pipe(fd);
       run_pipe(commands, fd);
       j++;
       k = 0;
     }
     //more cases here
     else { //nothing special
       commands[k] = tokens[j];
       j++;
       k++;
     }
    }
    commands[k] = NULL;
    pipe(fd);
    run_command(commands, fd);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above code is meant to simulate a shell. It handles single commands and it handles the pipelining properly (i.e. ps | sort | wc is returning the correct output) however when the pipelining is done it returns an EOF which is caught by the condition in the loop with getchar(). If I try to ignore this EOF it segfaults. Am I leaving a pipe open somewhere and stdin is getting flooded? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes` and you'll find that `wait()` is not declared; add `#include <sys/wait.h>` and you'll find compilation errors.  This may or may not be the source of all of your trouble, but it will account for the segfault - you pass an integer where a pointer is expected.  FWIW: always compile with options about as stringent as those suggested, or maybe even more stringent (I usually use a few extra options: `-Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wstrict-prototypes` which require other minor changes to your code.)

Comment: With the calls to `wait()` fixed, I get comprehensible, non-crashing results.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler can you post a small snippet of the fixed wait? I have the import fixed but can't quite work out how to fix the wait/waitpids now

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I implemented the wait changes and that didn't really fix anything, it still spits out an EOF after calling something like ps | sort

Answer (score 1):

#### Compilation fixes

You need to add `#include <sys/wait.h>` and then fix the calls to `wait()`.  I used (twice):

```
int status;
int corpse = wait(&status);
printf("PID %d status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
```

Arguably, that should be a loop looking for a specific PID, or you should use `waitpid()` instead.  While debugging a shell, you want to know about every PID that exits and its status.

I ran `ps | wc' and got:

```
Starting myshell (mysh) 
..
..
mysh :: /usr/local/google/home/jleffler/soq -> ps | wc
PID 25960 status 0x0000
PID 25961 status 0x0000
      4      16     117
mysh :: /usr/local/google/home/jleffler/soq -> EOF Received, exiting...
```

If you mean "the code should have continued instead of getting EOF", then there's some more work to do.

---

#### Tangential issues

I note the line:

```
if (buff[0] == EOF || buff[0] == '\0')
```

The character in `buff[0]` is from a `read()` call.  It will never be EOF meaningfully; EOF is distinct from every character (hence `getchar()` returns an `int`).  This becomes significant later:

```
char c = 0;
while (c != '\n')
{
    c = getchar();
    if (c == EOF)
```

Since `c` is a `char`, you cannot reliably compare it with `EOF`.  You must store the result of `getchar()` in an `int`.

I'm not yet convinced these are the cause of the trouble, but you must be careful.

---

#### Probable cause

I think the trouble is in `run_pipe()` in the parent code (as amended):

```
    else
    {
        close(fd[1]);
        if (fd[0] != 0)
        {
            dup2(fd[0], 0);
        }
        int status;
        int corpse = wait(&status);
        printf("PID %d status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
    }
```

The `fd[0] != 0` condition will always be true (very improbable that it will be false), so you then change your shell's input to read from `fd[0]`.  You should review that; it means that you're reading standard input from the read end of the pipe to the child.  That's bad; you've lost your original input!

Your code also seems to have the parent waiting for the child to die, and then reads the pipe and echoes to standard output.  This is not a good idea; it is better to make the child (last child in the pipeline) write to the standard output directly.  There are two reasons for this:

1. The child might write more data than fits in a pipe, so it will block waiting for something to read its output, but the reader will be blocked waiting for the child to die, so you'll have a deadlock.
2. It slows things up, and output from the child may well be buffered instead of appearing timely on the terminal.

I'm a little sceptical about how a three-part pipeline would be handled.  You need two pipes created before you run the middle process of the three; I don't see that in your code.

Comment: That is what I mean... I'm not sure how to prevent that EOF from spitting out after the commands end.

Comment: In regards to your edits, the first one was definitely superfluous but the char c was working fine/is able to catch ctrl + d or generated EOF. If I just perform a single command, the shell works fine, if I do two commands however the shell does as above and spits out EOFs. If you remove the EOF catch in the main, it will segfault.

Comment: Pay attention: `read()` never returns EOF per se; EOF is an artefact of the standard I/O package and the `read()` call is not part of the standard I/O package.  `read()` indicates 'no more data' by returning 0 bytes read.  You can run into two problems (I wonder how often I've typed this): if plain `char` is signed, then ÿ (y-umlaut, U+00FF, LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS) gets misinterpreted as equivalent to EOF (assuming an 8859-1, 8859-15 codeset); if plain `char` is unsigned, then no character will match EOF.  Both behaviours are wrong.

Comment: That part makes sense, so I changed a couple things to integers instead of chars, but that on its own hasn't altered the EOFs coming out of the pipeline. I think it may have to do with stdin being dup2'ed but I'm not sure why it's spilling over.

Comment: Hmm... I thought that might be the issue, however it seems to work fine up to the end. Is there a way to fix the end or does the entire thing need to be reworked?

Comment: I'm probably going to need to claim another work break...until later this evening.  I need to review what you've got still more (to make sure I understood what's going on).  I think you'll end up modifying the code to remove the `dup2()` I highlighted; I need to see what else changes (or you do).

Comment: Alright, I sent the question to my professor, we'll see if he ever gets back to me. I appreciate all the effort, C just isn't my cup of tea.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue. It's probably not the right way to do it, but I saved a copy of stdin and used dup2 to reset it when the pipelining was finished.

```
int in_bak = dup(0);

//stuff

dup2(in_bak, 0);
close(in_bak);
```

Comment: Yes, that is a bit crude but effective enough.  Ultimately, you'll want to get your shell out of the business of echoing your pipeline's output, but that'll get you past the immediate hiccup.  I started to work on it, but there's a moderate amount of work to fix the code so it works orthodoxly.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeah... at this point the "hack job" is good enough for me.